# How can you enable auto-DataTemplate selection based on data type like you can with an items control?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol, contentpresenter, datatemplateselector

We're writing a very specialized `ItemsControl` which actually has three `ContentPresenter`'s per 'row', each bound to a different object (think poor-man's grid) instead of the more common one, like a `ListBox`.

Now with a `ListBox` if you don't explicitly specify either an `ItemTemplate` or an `ItemTemplateSelector`, there seems to be some internal selector that applies the template based purely on data type.  However, our `ContentPresenter`'s aren't picking them up.  We've also tried switching them to `ContentControl`'s instead, but that hasn't worked either.

Now I know I can simply write my own `DataTypeTemplateSelector` that does this, but I'm wondering if that functionality is already 'baked in' somewhere considered its used with so many `ItemsControl`'s (`ListBox`, `TreeView`, `ComboBox`', `DataGrid`, etc.) and according to this MSDN article...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

...it should work by default!  But again, it doesn't.

Here's our (pseudo) code...

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- These all work when the relevant items are in a ListBox,
         but not with stand-alone ContentPresenters or ContentControls -->

    <DataTemplate DataType="local:SomeTypeA">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={c:DataTypeNameConverter}}" Foreground="Blue" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="local::SomeTypeB">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={c:DataTypeNameConverter}}" Foreground="Purple" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="local::SomeTypeC">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={c:DataTypeNameConverter}}" Foreground="Purple" />
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- These don't pick up the templates -->
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Field1}" />
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Field2}" />

<!-- This however does -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
```

So... anyone want to take a stab at why not?

Comment: I have used `DataTemplates` with `ContentControls` many times in the past without a problem. Can you post your actual code instead of pseudocode? And does it work if you set DataType equal to `{x:Type local:SomeTypeA}` instead of just `"local:SomeTypeA"`?

Comment: Rachel, you're right.  It does work with the markup-extension `x:Type` for the reason that H.B. pointed out below... MSFT in their infinite wisdom deemed a property **called 'DataType'** is of type `Object` and not of type `System.Type` so unlike with the 'TargetType' of a style, for a DataTemplate you have to use the markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx), <strike>for whatever crazy reason</strike>, is of type `Object`, the `DataTemplates` hence have a `string` set in that property unless you use [`x:Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx).

---

**Edit:** There is a very good reason for the property being an object, as always those who can *(and do)* read are clearly at an advantage:

> If the template is intended for object data, this property contains the type name of the data object (as a string). To refer to the type name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension. If the template is intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name. See the documentation remarks for details about specifying a non-default namespace for the XML element.

Comment: Aaaaah!  That's why!  I'm so used to omitting the `x:Type` when specifying the `TargetType` in styles (where I'm assuming it's properly set as type `Type`) so by omitting it here too, where you're saying the type is `Object` (and you're right... WTFBBQ, MSFT?!) it instead gets interpreted as a simple string, and therefore never matches!  Great catch, especially since you know the 'Why!' (I almost wrote that wasn't needed until I saw your answer.)  Wonder if this should be reported as a bug to MS! (Also, rule of thumb: Always use the markup! Clearer and would have worked!) Tx again!